# Pika: Consume the next message even the last message was not acknowledged

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, pika

For server automation, we're trying to develop a tool, which can handle and execute a lot of tasks on different servers. We send the task and the server hostname into a queue. The queue is then consumed from a requester, which give the information to the ansible api. To achieve that we can execute more then one task at once, we're using threading.

Now we're stuck with the acknowledge of the message...

What we have done so far:
The `requester.py` consumes the queue and starts then a thread, in which the ansible task is running. The result is then sended into another queue. So each new messages creates a new thread. Is the task finished, the thread dies.
But now comes difficult part. We have to made the messages persistent, in case our server dies. So each message should be acknowledged **after** the result from ansible was sended back.

Our problem is now, when we try to acknowledged the message in the thread itselfs, there is no more "simultaneously" work done, because the `consume` of pika waits for the acknowledge. So how we can achieve, that the `consume` consumes messages and dont wait for the acknowledge? Or how we can work around or improve our little programm?

**requester.py**

```
  #!/bin/python

  from worker import *
  import ansible.inventory
  import ansible.runner
  import threading

  class Requester(Worker):
      def __init__(self):
          Worker.__init__(self)
          self.connection(self.selfhost, self.from_db)
          self.receive(self.from_db)

      def send(self, result, ch, method):
          self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                                     routing_key=self.to_db,
                                     body=result,
                                     properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                                     delivery_mode=2,
                                     ))

          print "[x] Sent \n" + result
          ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

      def callAnsible(self, cmd, ch, method):
          #call ansible api pre 2.0

          result =  json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
          self.send(result, ch, method)

      def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
          print(" [x] Received by requester %r" % body)
          t = threading.Thread(target=self.callAnsible, args=(body,ch,method,))
          t.start()
```

**worker.py**

```
  import pika
  import ConfigParser
  import json
  import os

  class Worker(object):
      def __init__(self):
          #read some config files

      def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
          raise Exception("Call method in subclass")

      def receive(self, queue):
          self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
          self.channel.basic_consume(self.callback,queue=queue)
          self.channel.start_consuming()

      def connection(self,server,queue):
          self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
                 host=server,
                 credentials=self.credentials))
          self.channel = self.connection.channel()
          self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue, durable=True)
```

We're working with Python 2.7 and pika 0.10.0.

And yes, we noticed in the pika FAQ: http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/faq.html
that pika is not thread safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable auto-acknowledge and set the prefetch count to something bigger then 1, depending on how many messages would you like your consumer to take.

Here is how to set prefetch
`channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)`, found [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! How can I overlock this prefetch count. This does all the magic.

Comment: @Rumpli I have added this to the answer. Now I'm gonna go on my own damage here, but since you are new here I'll explain shortly about upvoting and accepting answers: If the answer helps you, give it an up vote. If it solves you problem, give it an upvote and accept. Here you have only accepted without upvote, but you didn't try it to is if it works :) Maybe just upvote for now, and once you verify accept as well. Someone please correct me if I didn't explain this voting/accepting correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I tried this out and with setting the 'channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)' to more then '1', it does more then one task at the time. And i tried to upvote your answer to, but as long as I dont have 15 reputation, it will not display it... :(